# 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'

Tags: angular, sqlite, .net-core

I'm new in .net core. When I write in VS code terminal

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I got the following message.

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (33ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
      "MigrationId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
      "ProductVersion" TEXT NOT NULL
  );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
Applying migration '20230820051454_InitialCreate'.
Applying migration '20230820051454_InitialCreate'.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  CREATE TABLE "Products" (
      "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Products" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      "Name" INTEGER NOT NULL
  );
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
  Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
  VALUES ('20230820051454_InitialCreate', '7.0.10');
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20230820051454_InitialCreate', '7.0.10');
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'.
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'.
```

I have the following code in appsettings.development.jason

```
{
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
  }
},
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=skinet.db"
 }
}
```

in StoreContext.cs file have

```
namespace API.Data
{
 public class StoreContext:DbContext
{

    public StoreContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    
}
}
```

And in Program.cs file have

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreContext> (opt=>
{

opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

});
```

Is there any one who can help me in this regard? Thanks.

I'm new in .net core. When I write in VS code terminal

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I got the following message.

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (33ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
      "MigrationId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
      "ProductVersion" TEXT NOT NULL
  );
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
Applying migration '20230820051454_InitialCreate'.
Applying migration '20230820051454_InitialCreate'.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  CREATE TABLE "Products" (
      "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Products" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      "Name" INTEGER NOT NULL
  );
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
  ................


SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'.
```

I have the following code in appsettings.development.jason

```
{
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information"
  }
},
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=skinet.db"
 }
}
```

in StoreContext.cs file have

```
namespace API.Data
{
 public class StoreContext:DbContext
{

    public StoreContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    
}
}
```

And in Program.cs file have

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreContext> (opt=>
{

opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

});
```

How to create _EFmigrationHistory or remove the problem? Is there any one who can help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the debug launch profile values that I had changed while debugging from Development to Production. I had not specified the connection string setting on the production app settings file. I just changed ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from Production to Development.

Comment: This is my launchSettings.jason file content.   {
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",  
  "profiles": {    
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,      
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}